# value not updating when transition is in progress

Tags: lua, coronasdk

```
FuelGaugeArrow:rotate( 75 )
local FuelDecreaseAngle = 150 / FuelLevelMax

local function BurnFuel(event)
  --transition.to( FuelGaugeArrow, { rotation = FuelGaugeArrow.rotation - FuelDecreaseAngle } )
  FuelGaugeArrow.rotation = FuelGaugeArrow.rotation - FuelDecreaseAngle
  FuelLevel = FuelLevel -1
  if FuelLevel <=0 then
    OutOfFuel()
  end
end
local FuelBurn = timer.performWithDelay( 1000, BurnFuel , 0)
```

The FuelGaugeArrow rotation value is updated by another function (when the rocket picks up a fuel barrel, it increases the value):

```
local function ScrollExtras(event)
   if FuelGaugeArrow.rotation + FuelIncreaseAngle <= 75 then 
      FuelGaugeArrow.rotation = FuelGaugeArrow.rotation + FuelIncreaseAngle
   else
      FuelGaugeArrow.rotation = 75
   end
end
Runtime:addEventListener( "enterFrame", ScrollExtras )
```

This works fine in the code above, but when I use the commented-out code, i.e. when I try to use transition to move the arrow, it only works when there is no transition going on at that precise moment. The updated value is not picked up by the BurnFuel function when transition is in progress.

I'm sure there's a better way to do this, so please enlighten me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either have to cancel previous transition before starting new, or wait till previous ends before starting new. The transition.to() returns a reference to a transition object which can be paused etc. For example,

```
local fuelTrans

local function BurnFuel(event)
    if fuelTrans ~= nil then 
        fuelTrans.cancel()
        fuelTrans = transition.to( FuelGaugeArrow, ... )
    end
    ...
end
```

The second method (wait till first complete) is probably not what you want, plus it involves setting onComplete parameter to a listener, but if you prefer that it is explained in [transition.to](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/transition/to.html).

Comment: @Bompaization Good to hear. You can accept the answer so it can be closed.